# Cannot change file permission and ownership

Tags: permissions, 20.04, chmod, chown

I'm using Google Cloud with Ubuntu 20.04 and using Guacamole to RDP into the machine. I have created a bunch of users and wanted to change folder permissions and file permissions of the files I'll be copying into the users home. If I check from root, all the files seem to have right ownership and permissions but as soon as I login from the user the files seem to belong to root with only read permissions. Any idea why this is happening?